# Can I create vue-cli project without Git?

Tags: git, vue.js, vuejs2, project

When I create a vue-cli project, by default, comes with initialized Git. So, I want to know if there is any kind of flag or something to create a template without it.

Comment: If `vue-cli` didn't provide a way of not using git, you could always just delete the `.git` directory and `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the docs:](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)

> Usage: `create [options] <app-name>`
>
> create a new project powered by vue-cli-service

```
Options:

  -p, --preset <presetName>       Skip prompts and use saved or remote preset
  -d, --default                   Skip prompts and use default preset
  -i, --inlinePreset <json>       Skip prompts and use inline JSON string as preset
  -m, --packageManager <command>  Use specified npm client when installing dependencies
  -r, --registry <url>            Use specified npm registry when installing dependencies

  -g, --git [message|false]       Force / skip git initialization, optionally specify initial commit message
  -n, --no-git                    Skip git initialization

  -f, --force                     Overwrite target directory if it exists
  -c, --clone                     Use git clone when fetching remote preset
  -x, --proxy                     Use specified proxy when creating project
  -b, --bare                      Scaffold project without beginner instructions
  -h, --help                      Output usage information
```

Answer (score 4):

Run this command:

```
vue create project-name --no-git
```